# Hide total shipping on Cart page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, order-summary

I tried to hide the value of shipping method in checkout detail (summary) like in the picture below. Which file in checkout i should change?
[image: checkout summary]

Comment: Do you want to hide on Cart page or Checkout page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it via xml layout `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`:

app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Tested on Magento 2.2 version.

Comment: Great!! It's works fine, thank you.But how could i change the subtotal value, tax value, and discount value on that summary?

Comment: `change the subtotal value, tax value, and discount value on that summary? ` What do you mean?

Comment: On that summary (like at the picture), there's Subtotal. How can i change the value?

Comment: Subtotal should be changed from Backend logic. Should not do it via Logic.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to change the subtotal?

Comment: I need to change the value, because i count those value from my own web services.

Comment: could you check it here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199022/change-total-value-in-checkout-summary

Comment: Yes. I saw your new question.

Comment: This code removes the shipping cost from totals, but shipping cost is still added to Grand Total. How can I remove that?